# Configurar un layout para cada orientación de pantalla Portratit y Landscape

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

estoy tratando de mostrar una vista diferente en cada orientación de pantalla, para lo cual tengo un fragment y dos layouts, un archivo xml para la vista **Portrait** (vertical) en la carpeta layout; y otro archivo con el mismo nombre en la nueva carpeta layout-land.

El problema que tengo es que los dos archivos xml tienen componentes diferentes y en el caso del Portratit existe un ViewPager que está siendo referenciado desde el fichero Java, cuando está mostrandose esta vista encuentra el ViewPager, pero al rotar el dispositivo no lo encuentra pues en el layout-land solo muestro un ImageView.

Nosé si sea posible generar una estructura condicional que me permita usar los componentes según la orientación que se esté usando.

A continiación copio el código del fragment y los dos archivos xml, además al final indico el error que me muestra en Logcat. muchas gracias por la ayuda.

**Fragment_Home**

```
public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

//ViewPager
ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipeAadapter adapter;

public Fragment_Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //ViewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAadapter(getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}   
}
```

**Vista Porttrait: layout/fragment_home**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3e3d3d"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.fragmentos.Fragment_Home">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:background="#3e3d3d">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Vista Landscape: land/fragment_home**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#1F2346"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.fragmentos.Fragment_Home">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#282e60">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sede_tagaste"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Mensaje Logcat**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.fragmentos.Fragment_Home.onCreateView(Fragment_Home.java:47)
```

La linea de error, cuando busca la vista landscape se refiere a: `viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Agrego una forma de como evitar se pierda la instancia del viewPager, y no se pierdan los datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones:

1- Haces validaciones para evitar nullpointers :

```
  View viewPagerView = v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
   if (viewPagerView != null ) {
      viewPager = (ViewPager)viewPagerView;
      adapter = new CustomSwipeAadapter(getContext());
      viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

2- Usa un fragmento(clase) distinto según la orientación

Comment: Muchas gracias #diegoveloper.

Answer (score 2):

En este caso puedes realizar la validación para evitar un `NullPointerException` al tener una instancia del `ViewPager` con valor Null,

```
 View viewPagerView = v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

   if (viewPagerView != null ) {
      viewPager = (ViewPager)viewPagerView;
      adapter = new CustomSwipeAadapter(getContext());
      viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

Sin embargo en algunos casos no se mostrarán los datos ya que no configuro un `Adapter` porque la instancia de `viewPagerView` tiene valor null, ¿Esto no sería una solución real ya que no mostraría datos?

En este caso una forma de "solucionar" los issues relacionados con rotación es definir en el `AndroidManifest.xml` para la `Activity` que cargara los `Fragmentes`, la propiedad :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

ejemplo:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias #Jorgesys

Comment: @IvanAlfredo al contrario más información para que tengas varias formas de solucionar un problema, saludos!