# Como finalizar un fragment al cambiar a otro fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo una pequeña aplicación con un `BottomNavigationView`, he agregado tres botones, con el primer botón muestra un `fragment`_home, en este `fragment` hay un `viewpager` el cual tiene como objetivo ***mostrar un slide de imágenes***, se ha configurado un temporizador `TimerTask` para el intervalo entre las imágenes.

El problema que tengo es que cuando me voy a otro `fragment` y vuelvo las transiciones se alteran en el tiempo en que se muestran, es como si mientras estoy en la otra vista, quedaran en espera y una vez vuelvo a este `fragment` empiezan a ejecutarse los tiempos entre las imágenes visualmente sin orden.

***Pienso que si al pasar a otra vista o fragment sería bueno finalizar este fragment.***

Estoy usando `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);` para habilitar `onBackPressed` para volver entre fragmentos, y leí sobre usar `fragmentManager.popBackStack()`; pero no me ha funcionado. Si me he hecho entender agradezco su ayuda, a continuación comparto código:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Fragment home = new Fragment_home();
    final Fragment dash =  new Fragment_Dashboard();
    final Fragment notif = new Fragment_notifications();

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Fragment_home()).commit();
    }

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, home).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.dashboard) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, dash).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.notifications) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, notif).commit();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Fragment_home**

```
public class Fragment_home extends Fragment {

//ViewPager
ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipeAadapter adapter;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //ViewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAadapter(getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 3000, 4000);

    return v;
}

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(getActivity() != null) {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                    }else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==1){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                    }else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==2){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }
}

}
```

Proyecto completo en GitHub: **[PROYECTO](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/MenuInferior)**

Comment: Ivan te sugiero veas mi respuesta aquí:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/118826/34903 , si estas únicamente validando cuando no existe el viewPager en realidad se van a provocar otro tipo de problemas como un Adapter vacio.

Comment: En este caso edite el código quitando la validacion para evitar nullpointers if (viewPagerView != null ), ya que en este ejemplo no configuro la vista horizontal, en este caso el problema es con el temporizador. por eso busco la manera de reiniciar el fragment cada vez que haga onBackPressed, si lo puede mirar, está especifico para la pregunta, en **[GitHub](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/MenuInferior)**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes introducir en el ViewPager un Fragment que actúe como contenedor y que nos servirá de referencia. Dentro de nuestro PageAdapter:

```
// PagerAdapter class
public class SlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 public SlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
 }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
/*
* IMPORTANT: This is the point. We create a RootFragment acting as
* a container for other fragments
*/
 if (position == 0)
   return new RootFragment();
 else
   return new StaticFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return NUM_ITEMS;
}
}
```

Y la clase RootFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
/* Inflate the layout for this fragment */
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.root_fragment, container, false);

  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

/*
* When this container fragment is created, we fill it with our first
* "real" fragment
*/
  transaction.replace(R.id.root_frame, new FirstFragment());

  transaction.commit();

  return view;
}
```

Y ya, dentro de nuestro FirstFragment, podemos incluir enlaces a otro fragmento:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
/*
* IMPORTANT: We use the "root frame" defined in
* "root_fragment.xml" as the reference to replace fragment
*/
   trans.replace(R.id.root_frame, new SecondFragment());
/*
* IMPORTANT: The following lines allow us to add the fragment
* to the stack and return to it later, by pressing back
*/
   trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
   trans.addToBackStack(null);

   trans.commit();
  }
});
```